# Multiple Dex File build error following NS 2.5 Upgrade

Tags: android, nativescript

Following the upgrade to Nativescript 2.5 I'm receiving a build error that I'm not quite sure how to fix. The error is:

> Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForF0F1F2F3F4F5F6Debug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files
>   define Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/MessengerCompat$1;

I've spent some time looking into the issue and a Multiple Dex file exception seems to normally mean that two different versions of a dependency are being referenced. Yet I can't seem to find anything which relates to > MessengerCompat in the gradle files of any of my dependencies.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case you could try to remove `node_modules`, `platforms` and `hooks` folders from your project and to clear npm cache with `npm cache clear`.

Then try to rebuild the app with `tns run android`.

It would also help if you could share the `package.json` file of the project.